# HTML5 localStorage across files?

Tags: html

Is HTML5 storage shared across other HTML files?

For example if I have files..

`index.html` and `index2.html` and I set a key `info` equal to `null` in index can I retrieve this value in `index2.html`? If not, is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one localStorage object per origin, the origin being the combination of protocol, host and port. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. So if all your HTML files come from the same protocol/host/port, then they will share the same localStorage.